# Dynamically Updating JS Variable Containing CSS Styles

Tags: javascript, css

The project I'm working on has these cards on the screen that change with both screen width and a selector at the top. What I would want to do is make sure that the variable created here:

```
var element = document.getElementById('front'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
    width = style.getPropertyValue('width');
```

is updated constantly as the screen width changes and the width of the cards themselves change. By the way, width is the width of the card, which only shows me the original value, not changed values. I proved this by trying to log it in the console window in Chrome after changing the actual width of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an event to the [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) like this:

```
window.onresize = function() {  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update your values on resize stop then you may need to use debounce function as well to reduce CPU load.. Because on each pixel change you will get DOM elements which is kind of slow in terms of DOM operations

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        }, wait);
        if (immediate && !timeout) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

var element, width, style;
var myEfficientFn = debounce(function() {
  element = document.getElementById('front'),
  style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
  width = style.getPropertyValue('width');
}, 250);

window.addEventListener('resize', myEfficientFn);
```